# How to change controller variable in service angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This's my service. I've got variable  isPolygonDrawingEnded there.

```
angular
    .module('gillie.clients.app')
    .service('mapDrawingService', mapDrawingService);

mapDrawingService.$inject = ['$ngBootbox', '$translate', 'fitPolygonService', 'mapCommonService'];

function mapDrawingService($ngBootbox, $translate, fitPolygonService, mapCommonService) {
    var self = this;

    var map;
    var polygonFeatures;
    var stopDrawingAction;
    var isPolygonDrawingEnded = false;
    var isDrawingMode = true;

self.startNewPolygonDrawing = function (afterDrowed) {

        fitPolygonService.suggestPoint(isDrawingMode);
        var modify = createModifyInteractionToPolygonFeatures();

        var draw = createDrawInteraction();
        attachDrawEvents(draw, afterDrowed);
        map.addInteraction(draw);

        stopDrawingAction = function() {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            map.removeInteraction(modify);
        };
    };
        var attachDrawEvents = function (draw, afterDrowed) {
        draw.on('drawend', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            afterDrowed();
            isPolygonDrawingEnded = true;

            if (fitPolygonService.isPolygonsExist()) {
                var geometry = e.feature.getGeometry();
                e.feature.setGeometry(fitPolygonService.fitPolygon(geometry));
            }
        });
}
```

This is my controller. Here I need to change `$scope.showCountButton` when `mapDrawingService.isPolygonDrawingEnded == true`. **So how can I know that value in service is changed ?**

```
angular
    .module('gillie.clients.app')
    .controller('regionController', regionController);

regionController.$inject = ['$q', '$filter', '$scope', '$ngBootbox', '$translate', 'regionService', 'mapService', 'mapDrawingService', 'modalService', 'regionCommonService', 'alertService', 'nominatimCommonService', 'populationService', 'provinceCommonService', 'provinceService', 'rx'];

function regionController($q, $filter, $scope, $ngBootbox, $translate, regionService, mapService, mapDrawingService, modalService, regionCommonService, alertService, nominatimCommonService, populationService, provinceCommonService, provinceService, rx) {

    $scope.showCountButton = false;

        $scope.startRegionSelection = function (region) {

        $scope.isSavingAvailable = true;
        $scope.showCountButton = false;
        if (currentEditingRegion && region && currentEditingRegion.Id === region.Id) {
            return;
        }

        if(region)
            mapService.clearRegion(region);

        if (currentEditingRegion && !region) {
            mapDrawingService.continuePolygonDrawing();
            return;
        }

        if (region) {
            mapDrawingService.stopPolygonDrawing();
            mapDrawingService.clearMap();

            currentEditingRegion = region;
            mapDrawingService.startExistPolygonDrawing(region.Name, region.CoordinatesJson);
            return;
        }

        mapDrawingService.startNewPolygonDrawing(function () {            
                    $scope.showCountButton = true           
        });
    };
```

When I use `mapDrawingService.startNewPolygonDrawing` function - the value of `showCountButton` changes but view doesn't. `$scope.$apply` produces this exception:

```
[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/04/angularjs-notifying-about-changes-from-services-to-controllers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing the callback function it is no longer in the scope of the controller which is why the view is not updating. You can use promises instead since you are asynchronous draw event.

**Service**

```
mapDrawingService.$inject = ['$q', '$ngBootbox', '$translate', 'fitPolygonService', 'mapCommonService'];

function mapDrawingService($q, $ngBootbox, $translate, fitPolygonService, mapCommonService) {
  var self = this;

  var map;
  var polygonFeatures;
  var stopDrawingAction;
  var isPolygonDrawingEnded = false;
  var isDrawingMode = true;

  self.startNewPolygonDrawing = function() {
    fitPolygonService.suggestPoint(isDrawingMode);
    var modify = createModifyInteractionToPolygonFeatures();

    var draw = createDrawInteraction();
    var promiseObj = attachDrawEvents(draw);
    map.addInteraction(draw);

    stopDrawingAction = function() {
      map.removeInteraction(draw);
      map.removeInteraction(modify);
    };

    return promiseObj;
  };
  var attachDrawEvents = function(draw) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (fitPolygonService.isPolygonsExist()) {
          var geometry = e.feature.getGeometry();
          e.feature.setGeometry(fitPolygonService.fitPolygon(geometry));
        }

        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

**Controller**

```
mapDrawingService.startNewPolygonDrawing().then(function() {
  $scope.showCountButton = true
});
```

Comment: angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.startRegionSelection (gillie.clients.region.controller.js:76)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14432), <anonymous>:4:297)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15485)
    at callback (angular.js:25018)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17329)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25023)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)

i`ve this exceptin in browser

Comment: Sorry, it should just be `return promiseObj;` not `return promiseObj.promise;`. I fixed it in the example above.

Comment: it`s realy good solution. thank you. Now i need to resolve another problem. Earlier i can't draw second polygon. [Screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/0loDc)